# Simple HTML Audio Track with a Few Variables

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have an API that controls music playback.
Audio is not played through the browser, but via a Discord bot.

## Desired Result

[image: High Budget Diagram]

**Variables**:

- **current**: the current position of the track (e.g. 2:30)
- **max**: the max position/length of the track (e.g. 3:00)

**Events**:

- **move**: calls moveTo(position)
- **end**: calls reset()

Is there any libraries that can achieve something similar to this, or would I have to make a custom one to do something like this?

I will be using Angular 9 to do this.

**Audio Demo**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VowfGyZGS_Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the `<audio>` tag? You can add this to your html document and get a audio player (the browser's built in one). Here is an example https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp. If you do not want to use the browser's built in one you can use a library like [plyr](https://plyr.io/) or [audio.js](http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/)

**EDIT**

You say you want a Discord bot. Well I do not think there is any API for what you are looking for. Can you describe more what you want this bot to do?

Comment: I have the music functionality, but I just want a simple slider/track for the music.

Comment: I did some research and I am fairly certain that you cannot have interactive elements in a discord chat. You could post a link to a web server running the application.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VowfGyZGS_Y

Comment: so do you need a audio trackbar?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for not explaining it well enough. Basically, I'd just like to control the position with a track slider, on the music player.

Comment: You can use the range control. The W3schools website has documentation on this. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp